# executing another php from php like an ajax call

Tags: php

I have a php file where I build a mail, I call this php from javascript via ajax passing one parameter.
But I have a situation where I have a php where I am writing into database and once finished I need to call this php mail, build a mail then send.
Using an `include` I only get this mail php included in the php where I am writing into database: how I can run this php to build that mail and send once I finish to write into database?.... thanks! Cheers!

Comment: When you include a PHP file it basically (more or less) adds the code of that file to that spot in the file that included it.  If the included file contains functions then you can call those functions.  It's not clear what's stopping you from doing that.  Perhaps you just need to organize your code into functions, classes, etc. instead of just executing everything directly?  Then you can invoke whatever functionality you need when and where you need it, which is going to work a lot better than the approach you describe of the server making an HTTP request to itself just to run code in itself.

Comment: I totally agree with David. You should be able to reuse functionalities if your code is well organized. Anyway, if you still need to do something like an AJAX call from PHP I think you need cURL, but it would be quite crazy if we talk about doing a cURL call from/to pieces in the same code...